# How to allow certain ports open to world only for certain security groups in Cloud Custodian?

Tags: amazon-ec2, policy, aws-security-group, standards-compliance, cloudcustodian

I have this in my policy to allow only 80 and 443 open to world.

```
      "or": [
        {
          "Cidr": {
            "value": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }, 
          "type": "ingress", 
          "OnlyPorts": [
            80, 
            443
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "CidrV6": {
            "value": "::/0"
          }, 
          "type": "ingress", 
          "OnlyPorts": [
            80, 
            443
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Now, I want to allow only 8080 and 8081 to selected security groups, not for all security groups. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit particular security groups only. Just open the ports there and that will do it.

Comment: If I open ports, it will applied for all the security groups. Is there any way I can add the security group id in policy file?

Comment: How about creating new sg with the ports open and attaching it to other sgs you want open?

Comment: Once I create new security group with port open, lambda function will get triggered and it will delete the rules which are open to world.

Answer (score 0):

Add a value filter using a key and array of values to exclude the Security Groups you don't want to match

Answer (score 0):

For IPV4:

```
resource: security-group
    filters:
      - tag:c7n_exception: absent
      - type: ingress
        OnlyPorts: [80,443]
        Cidr:
          value: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

For IPV6:

```
    resource: security-group
    filters:
      - tag:c7n_exception: absent
      - type: ingress
        OnlyPorts: [80,443]
        CidrV6:
          value: "::/0"
```

More filters

```
filters:
  - and:
            - type: security-group
              key: GroupId
              #key: SecurityGroups[].GroupID  
              op: not-in
              value:
                - sg-0db5e1ab7s8323
```